# Custom Django Rest JWT Login

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I'm trying to write custom jwt login view for django rest api authentication.
But it doesn't work, and I don't know why.Could you help me to fix this code or put some example. Thanks in advance.

my serializer:

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    token = serializers.CharField(max_length=256)
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=128)
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True,
                                     required=True,
                                     style={
                                         'input_type': 'password',
                                         'placeholder': 'password'
                                     })
```

my view:

```
from .serializers import LoginSerializer

class UserLogin(APIView):
    """
        POST login/
    """
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        username = request.data.get('username', '')
        password = request.data.get('password', '')
        user = auth.authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            serializer = LoginSerializer(self.queryset,
                data={
                    'token': jwt_encode_handler(jwt_payload_handler(user)),
                    'username': username,
                    'password': password,
                }
            )
            if serializer.is_valid():
                return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

Comment: You aren't using LoginSerializer to create an instance so may I ask why you have the password write_only field in there? Also when you say TokenSerializer in your view do you mean LoginSerializer? If not, what is LoginSerializer there for and where is the code for TokenSerializer?

Comment: It was mistake there, I'm using LogiSerializer

Answer (score 2):

You can simply just dump your token into the json and not even use a serializer. You are providing the data and format here so you shouldn't need to validate any user input.

```
class UserLogin(APIView):
    """
        POST login/
    """
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        username = request.data.get('username', '')
        password = request.data.get('password', '')
        user = auth.authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return Response({'token': jwt_encode_handler(jwt_payload_handler(user)),
                    'username': user.username})

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```